# Points and lines won't connect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to connect the dots in my plot and tried `geom_point()`+`geom_line()` but it won't work.

The code below just has it for the points. Does anyone have any ideas why `geom_line()` does not add any line?

```
DensityE = read.csv("DensityElk.csv", header = TRUE)
str(DensityE)

DensityE$Date <- factor(DensityE$Date, levels=
        c("20-May","3-Jun",
      "17-Jun","1-Jul","16-Jul", 
      "22-Jul", "15-Aug"), order=TRUE)

ggplot(data=DensityE, aes(Date,Density)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(Genus)), size = 4, 
position="jitter") + 
theme_bw() + xlab("Date") +
ylab("Density per m2") + ggtitle("COP 1992") +
opts(legend.key = theme_blank()) + 
opts (legend.title = theme_blank())+
opts(legend.text = theme_text(size=9))
```

Comment: Please add [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What does `DensityElk.csv` look like?

Comment: Hi, the subset of the data is:1-Jul Epeorus 3.5
16-Jul Epeorus 3.25
22-Jul Epeorus 1
3-Jun Rhyacophila 1
17-Jun Rhyacophila 0.75

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did try using the code on stack flow before but nothing would work.

Answer (score 6):

Because you're using a factor (`Date`) on the x-axis, `ggplot2` won't automatically connect the lines across x values.  Two solutions are (1) `geom_line(aes(group=Genus))` or (2) `geom_line(aes(x=as.numeric(Date)))`

Construct data frame:

```
DensityE <- data.frame(
    Date=c("1-Jul","16-Jul","22-Jul","3-Jun","17-Jun"),
    Genus=c("Epeorus","Epeorus","Epeorus","Rhyacophila","Rhyacophila"),
    Density=c(3.5,3.25,1,1,0.75))
```

Make the plot: I have made a few changes

- changed `theme_blank` to `element_blank` and `opt` to `theme` for consistency with recent `ggplot2` releases
- removed jittering -- if you want jittering *and* points and lines that connect the same points, you will have to add the jittering manually to the y values.

Code:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data=DensityE, aes(Date,Density)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = factor(Genus)), size = 4)+
    geom_line(aes(group=Genus))+
 theme_bw() + xlab("Date") +
 ylab("Density per m2") + ggtitle("COP 1992") +
 theme(legend.key = element_blank()) + 
 theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
 theme(legend.text = element_text(size=9))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it still didn't work. I have attached a sample of the dataset with Date, Genus and Density. I still can't figure out how to get it to work. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: 1-Jul Epeorus 3.5
16-Jul Epeorus 3.25
22-Jul Epeorus 1
3-Jun Rhyacophila 1
17-Jun Rhyacophila 0.75

Comment: Thank you! that did work but only on the subset of data that i gave you. Unfortunately my data sheep is incredibly big and it didn't work when i used the code for the whole set of data. Im sorry, I'm really new to this and am struggling. Is there a way that i can use my big data set or do i have to make a data frame like you did for the whole thing? There would be about 300 density measurements, dates and genus.